# wrong location opened in Open File Dialog in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2016

```
Private Sub ViewBlueprintToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ViewBlueprintToolStripMenuItem.Click

        Dim brgy As String = txtAddress.Text.Split(",")(0)
        Dim municipality As String = txtAddress.Text.Split(",")(1)
        Dim yearA As Date = dateApproved.Value
        Dim yearString As String = Format(yearA, "yyyy").ToString

        lblbrgy.Text = brgy
        muni.Text = municipality
        year.Text = yearString


        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\Desktop\APPROVED PLANS SOFT COPY\" & municipality & "\" & brgy & "\" & yearString & ""
        lblAdd.Text = OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "img files *.png|*.bmp|*.jpg|*.jpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()


    End Sub
```

Good day.

I want to open the folder in that specific directory stated in the initial directory. but whenever i do so, it always opens the wrong folder. brgy, municipality, and year are both retrieved from a database and converted as a string.

But when i displayed the initial directory's path using label, to see if it has the correct path, it displays its correct path. what seems to be the problem with my code?

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Apart from anything else, we can't copy code from a picture. Post the code as text, formatted as code.

Comment: here it is sir.

Comment: `brgy` and `municipality` variables could contain white spaces from the split. Append `...Split(",")(0).Trim()` & `...Split(",")(1).Trim()` method and try.

Comment: Would also suggest looking at the Path.Combine() method.  Will allow you construct the InitialDirectory value in a much more robust way